# Matlab .desktop file

Tags: .desktop, matlab

(This is not about creating a launcher in the dock or anything like that.)

When I navigate into a folder with some Matlab .m files, and simply do

```
matlab myscript.m
```

in the terminal, it launches Matlab with working directory set to where the file is.

*This has some perks:* If there is also a startup.m file in the directory - and therefore in Matlab path - Matlab will notice and run it.

I tried to replicate this functionality with a .desktop file, so I could click an .m file (recognized as objective C by Ubuntu...) with the same results as if I run it from terminal, but no luck.

Here is what I have tried:

I put `text/x-objcsrc=Matlab.desktop` in `/home/jakub/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

and created this desktop file in `/home/jakub/.local/share/applications`

```
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=matlab -desktop
Name=Matlab
Icon=/home/jakub/Pictures/icons/Apps-Matlab-icon.png
Categories=Development
```

When I click an .m file, it launches Matlab, but it is not equivalent to running it from the terminal (see above): Mainly, work dir is set to Matlab's default, instead of where the script is, and the script does not open, just plain Matlab with empty editor.

I also tried this:

```
Exec=matlab -desktop -r "edit %f"
```

which opens the file but does not set the work dir

```
Exec=matlab -desktop -r "cd %d"
```

which changes the work dir, but *after* Matlab is run, which means it will not run the code in startup.m (so it is not equivalent to doing `matlab myscript.m` in the terminal).

Is there any way of *perfectly* mimicking `matlab myscript.m` as run from the terminal, but in a desktop file?

Answer (score 6):

I had the a similar issue, when I tried to set Matlab up manually.

Eventually, I ran:
`sudo apt-get install matlab-support`
and followed installation instructions. This just adds Matlab to the Dashboard.
The resulting matlab.desktop file reads:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=matlab -desktop
Name=MATLAB
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/matlab.png
Categories=Development;Math;Science
Comment=Scientific computing environment
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=com-mathworks-util-PostVMInit
```

**To open .m files in matlab by clicking on them** I used the Ubuntu GUI to set it to open those files with the command:

```
matlab -desktop -r "open %U;"
```

This both opens the file in Matlab and sets the current working directory to where the file is located (at least with Matlab 2016b).

I hope this information helps.

Comment: "I used the Ubuntu GUI to set it to open those files with the command": on Nautilus, Ubuntu 20.04, I'm not seeing how to do this. I can right click on a .m file > properties > open with, but that doesn't give me the option to specify the command like this. Any suggestions?